# No puedo instalar el angular cli ni el Ionic en Linux UBuntu 16.04

Tags: ionic, angular, cordova

estoy usando ubuntu 16.04, hace tiempo que ya quiero instalar angular cli, probe con el comando

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Me sale en la terminal un error asi:

```css
pm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /home/juanse/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /home/juanse/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /home/juanse/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/@angular
npm ERR! path /home/juanse/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/home/juanse/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/home/juanse/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli'
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/home/juanse/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/home/juanse/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/juanse/.npm/_logs/2018-06-04T16_09_24_688Z-debug.log
```

Y para el ionic uso el comando:

```
npm install -g ionic
```

Y me sale el error:

```css
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /home/juanse/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/ionic npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /home/juanse/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules npm ERR! path /home/juanse/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/ionic npm ERR! code EACCES npm ERR! errno -13 npm ERR! syscall access npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied,
access '/home/juanse/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/ionic' npm ERR! {
  Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/home/juanse/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/ionic' npm ERR! stack: 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/home/juanse/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/ionic\'', npm ERR! errno: -13, npm ERR! code: 'EACCES', npm ERR! syscall: 'access', npm ERR! path: '/home/juanse/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/ionic'
}

npm ERR! npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system. npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user npm ERR! npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue,
please double-check the npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories,
or try running npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended). npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR! /home/juanse/.npm/_logs/2018-06-04T16_13_38_163Z-debug.log
```

Ayuda por favor, e investiga y probado de todo pero nada logra arreglarlo

Answer (score 1):

Es un problema de permiso, debe usar **sudo** antes de los comandos, por ejemplo:

```
sudo npm install -g ionic

sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Check:

```
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```

En caso de error:

```
sudo npm install -g node-gyp
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```

**Sudo**, el único comando para gobernarlos a todos. Significa "super usuario do!" Pronunciado como "sue masa" Como administrador de sistemas Linux o usuario avanzado, es uno de los comandos más importantes en su arsenal. ... Es mucho mejor que iniciar sesión como root, o usar el comando su "cambiar usuario"

Comment: AHora me sale asi [/home/juanse/.npm-packages/bin/ng -> /home/juanse/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng

> @angular/cli@6.0.7 postinstall /home/juanse/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli
> node ./bin/ng-update-message.js

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

+ @angular/cli@6.0.7
updated 1 package in 25.08s
]

Comment: sudo npm install -g ionic cordova

Comment: @JuansePortillo actualizado mi respuesta

Comment: Me sale lo mismo

Comment: ejecuta npm -v y dime qué versión tienes

Comment: pero ya no tienes errores, es solo una advertencia

Comment: *extra* para actualizar todo tu sistema:

sudo apt-get update 

sudo apt-get upgrade

Comment: 6.1.0
es mi version de npm